# In Strapi i can get a specific product but how do I get ALL products?

Tags: api, strapi

I set up a product collection type, added three records and in the browser type

***localhost:1337/api/products/2*** and it correctly displays record 2:
{"data":{"id":2,"attributes":{"title":"Gillette Razor","price":9.99,"description":"/assets/product-images/product-2.png","featured":true,"createdAt":"2022-08-20T12:23:10.685Z","updatedAt":"2022-08-20T12:29:45.062Z","publishedAt":null}},"meta":{}}
(also works for /1  and /3, showing those products).

But, when I try to see ALL products by typing:
***localhost:1337/api/products*** I get:
{"data":[],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":0,"total":0}}}

I have given "public" access to "find" and "findOne". Server is running. *Why is it not producing a list of the three products entered?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the data has to be "published" (default is "draft") for the /api/products to show all records, even though the /api/products/x had no issue revealing product x details without being published.

After marking the data as published ***localhost:1337/api/products*** now gives me ALL of my products:

{"data":[{"id":1,"attributes":{"title":"razor blade","price":1.99,"description":"/assets/product-images/product-1.png","featured":false,"createdAt":"2022-08-20T12:22:12.498Z","updatedAt":"2022-08-20T15:37:08.598Z","publishedAt":"2022-08-20T15:37:08.597Z"}},{"id":2,"attributes":{"title":"Gillette Razor","price":9.99,"description":"/assets/product-images/product-2.png","featured":true,"createdAt":"2022-08-20T12:23:10.685Z","updatedAt":"2022-08-20T15:37:01.649Z","publishedAt":"2022-08-20T15:37:01.648Z"}},{"id":3,"attributes":{"title":"Barber Razor","price":7.99,"description":"/assets/product-images/product-3.png","featured":null,"createdAt":"2022-08-20T12:23:52.749Z","updatedAt":"2022-08-20T15:36:52.579Z","publishedAt":"2022-08-20T15:36:52.577Z"}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":1,"total":3}}}